# Field Extensions and Number of Isomorphisms

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

[image]

The picture above is from Dummit and Foote, Third Edition. Later in the book, we find

[image]

Clearly, the condition of equality is not necessary, as seen by taking the polynomial $ f(x) =  ( x ^{2} - 2) ( x ^{2} - 2)  $, which is not separable, but its splitting field, $    \mathbb{Q}     ( \sqrt{2   }     )          $ also has two automorphisms, and the degree of extension over $ \mathbb{Q} $ is also $ 2 $.

However, in the book of Abstract Algebra by the author John A. Beachy, Third Edition, we find that

[image]

which disagrees with the definition given by Dummit and Foote. I realize that the terminology of Beachy is, according to Wikipedia, old fashioned, but I redid the proof of Proposition 5 with the "old" definition, and it seems that the condition of equality becomes necessary too.

**Question.** If we use Beachy's definition, does the equality condition in Proposition 5 become if and only if?

Comment: I think the right definition is the first one. It corresponds to the criterion that $f$ is separable if and only if $f\wedge f'=1$.

Comment: It seems to me that the words “with equality if $f(x)$ is separable over $F$” are a truth, which your example does not contradict, since it’s not separable.

Comment: You're missing my point. I am saying that the implication    

"_Equality_ $ \implies $ _separable_ 

is not true, which is the _converse_ to what Dummit and Foote propose.

Comment: In the definition taken from Beachy and Blair (*not* just Beachy; some well-known textbooks are Atiyah--MacDonald, Ireland & Rosen, and Griffiths & Harris, which are never referred to only by the first author's name alone), the definition of a separable field extension only refers to irreducible polynomials (minimal poly. is always irred.), and the definition of a perfect field should also refer to "every irreducible polynomial" rather than "every polynomial" over $F$. Then all problems go away.

Answer (score 3):

Everyone agrees that an irreducible polynomial over a field is separable iff it has distinct roots in an algebraic closure.  There is a well-known (standard?!?) lack of agreement as to when to call a reducible polynomial separable.

I prefer Dummit-Foote's definition, though I wish it stated explicitly that the roots are living in an algebraic closure.  As in @Bernard's comment, this definition renders the Derivative Criterion valid, and (thus) it is faithfully preserved by base extension: in plainer language that means that if $f \in F[t]$ and $K/F$ is any field extension, then $f$ is separable when regarded as a polynomial over $F$ iff $f$ is separable when regarded as a polynomial over $K$.  In Beachy-Blair's definition, this does not work upon passing from any imperfect field to its algebraic closure.

Having said that: I'm not sure I understand your complaint about the proposition in Dummit-Foote.  Is it that in the given case the polynomial is not separable according to their definition so the result doesn't apply, but if you used Beachy-Blair's definition you could apply the result?  This seems a bit superficial: the result is actually true whenever the finite *extension* $E/F$ is normal (i.e., the splitting field of some polynomial) and separable, as is a standard result in most field theory texts.  If you want to concentrate on polynomials, you can just observe that the splitting field of a polynomial depends only on the largest squarefree polynomial divisor: in other words, if $f = \prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{e_i}$ with each $p_i$ irrreducible, then the splitting field of $f$ is certainly equal to the splitting field of $\prod_{i=1}^r p_i$.

Ah, I found your question.  The answer is **yes**.

Comment: So, in a nutshell, if we use Beachy's definition, we have to say that a polynomial $ f \in   F[x]  $ is separable _with respect to the field_ $ F $ if its irreducible factors have distinct roots. Also, the equality condition in Proposition 5 becomes both _necessary_ and sufficient (the later, it already was), if we agree to use the aforementioned conditions. 

Say yes once more.

Comment: @swaqar: Okay: **yes**.

Comment: I meant that you reconfirm what I said was right. :P 

By the way, thanks for the insightful remark that the second definition is not field independent! :)